# Reopening Activity from Spinner in Android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-spinner, onitemselectedlistener

In a messaging app, in my `WriteMessageActivity`, I have a spinner for choosing who can see my messages.

I have three options
 - visible to everyone
 - my friends only
 - select friends

Now when I click `SelectFriends` from spinner it opens `ChooseContactsActivity`. From there I can select a number friends that can see my message.

When I select my contacts I click the `add button` in my `ChooseContactsActivity`, and pass those contacts back to `WriteMessageActivity`. It works fine.

**Now I have a small problem**, After I selected my friends, if I want to reopen `ChooseContactsActivity` again, I first have to select one of the other two options in the spinner (either `visible to everyone`, or `my friends only`), and then click on the select friends option again, I cannot click on the selected option directly to reopen it again.

Spinner:

```
vissibleToSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerVissibleTo);
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.spinner_vissible_to, R.layout.spinner_center_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_center_item);
vissibleToSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
vissibleToSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
     ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(14);
     ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setAllCaps(true);
     ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setAllCaps(true);

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                mShowTo.setText("0");
                break;
            case 1:
                mShowTo.setText("-1");
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Message will be visible to your friends only", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
            case 2:
                mShowTo.setText("TODO");
                Intent intent = new Intent(MessageActivity.this, ChooseContactsActivity.class); 
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
});
```

Comment: Did you finish ChooseContactsActivity ?

Comment: @SanjayKakadiya Yes I finish it when I press back, add or cancel.